# How to import external jquery file in component of angular 6?

Tags: angular, jquery-plugins

I am developing an angular 6 project.
I have one issue in importing the external jquery file(bootstrap-select.min.js).
I have installed all jquery files and also bootstrap-select jquery plugin by using npm install command.
And I have included the bootstrap-select like this in index.component.ts:

`import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';
import 'bootstrap-select';`

it is working when the project is loading for the first.
but when I click any link and then back to this page, it is not working.
What's the reason. please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in `angular.json` you will find a scripts property. Which should look something like this:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

Try adding `bootstrap-select.js` there and restarting your angular-cli webpack dev server and see if that fixes it.

Make sure it appears in the list after any dependencies.

Also, be careful there are 2 "scripts" entries in `angular.json` make sure you add it under `build.options.scripts`